# Java Flight Recorder - find file descriptor leak

Tags: java, profiling, jmc, jfr, java-mission-control

M Java application probably has a file descriptor leak, since I'm getting a `Too many open files` exception.

I'm running my application with JFR, and when I inspect File I/O I barely see any I/O count. Is it possible to use JFR for finding code which open files but not closes them?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, JFR can't track file handles.

You can change the threshold of the File Read and File Write event to 0 ns, so you will see every read and write, but there will be a lot of events. Not sure if it will help though.

You can change the threshold in the Recording Wizard, or Window -> Template Manager if you don't start the recording from JMC.